# How to hardcode size attributes of UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I subclassed a `UIView` as a bar (making a bar graph), how do I hardcode the size attributes for my `FirstBarView`?  I get the error:

> FirstBarView type does not have a member named frame?

```
import UIKit





    @IBDesignable class FirstBarView: UIView {


        @IBInspectable var FirstBarViewColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        FirstBarView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 20, 400)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self` instead of `FirstBarView`.
You are refreshing the class instead of a instance of the class.

```
@IBDesignable class FirstBarView: UIView {        
    @IBInspectable var FirstBarViewColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 20, 400)
    }
}


//To create a new class with a rect.

var myFirstBarView = FirstBarView()
myFirstBarView.drawRect(CGRectMake(0,0,200,50))
```

Comment: Thanks, now how to I make my hardcode override the size attributes in the inspector?

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand correctly. But if you want to know how to set the frame, you would replace `CGRectMake(…)` with `rect`. This will make the frame, as big as the `CGRect` that you pass using `FirstBarView().drawRecht(/*Create Custom Rect*/)`

Comment: Where would I pass in the x, y, width, height values?